# Retreiving sub-array indexes

Tags: php, arrays

Given `[1=>[4=>[]],3=>[2=>[]],0=>[6=>[]],8=>[2=>[]]]`, how can I obtain `[4,2,6]`?  I can obviously use a `foreach()` loop, but am interested whether a more concise solution is available.

```
<?php

$arr1=[
    1=>[4=>[]],
    3=>[2=>[]],
    0=>[6=>[]],
    8=>[2=>[]],
];
print_r($arr1);
$arr2=[4,2,6,2];
print_r($arr1);
$arr3=array_values(array_unique($arr2));
print_r($arr3);


Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 6
)
```

Comment: `$new = array_unique(array_map(function($value) { return array_keys($value)[0]; }, $arr1));
`

Comment: Thank you Mark.  Didn't know that `array_map()` was required.

Comment: Same idea: `var_dump(array_unique(array_column(array_map('array_keys',$arr1),0)));`

Comment: @user1032531 - As I'm sure the answers will tell yo, there's a number of different way you could do this, and not all use array_map()

Comment: @MarkBaker  I am sure there is!  I was messing around with `array_flip()`, but obviously had issues.

Comment: array_flip will give problems because the values that you need to flip to get the keys are also arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest one with `array_map` and `key` functions:

```
$result = array_unique(array_map(function($a){ return key($a); }, $arr1));
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [3] => 2
    [0] => 6
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know I didn't say so in the post, but will be using the results in a prepared statement so will need to apply `array_values()` to it.  jh1711's solution somehow already does so.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this:

```
$arr1=[
    1=>[4=>[]],
    3=>[2=>[]],
    0=>[6=>[]],
    8=>[2=>[]],
];
$arr2 = array_unique(array_reduce($arr1, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = array_merge($a, array_keys($b));
    return $a;
}, []));
print_r($arr2);
```

This is similar to the solution proposed in the first comment but this one will also work when you have more than one items in the inner arrays